# Which countries have the highest number of state owned enterprises after China?

Tags: economy, international, trade, communism, wto

> The state sector has always been an important element of many
> economies, including the most advanced ones. There are legitimate
> economic and non-economic reasons for state ownership and views on the
> role of government in the economy may differ across countries and
> political systems. State-owned enterprises (SOEs) can act on the basis
> of commercial considerations, or they may have non-commercial
> priorities. In certain circumstances they can be granted advantages
> that can potentially hinder market access in importing countries or
> affect export competition. **These advantages can take the form of
> direct subsidies, concessionary financing, state-backed guarantees,
> preferential regulatory treatment, exemptions from antitrust
> enforcement or bankruptcy rules, and others. Having effects on the
> global market, these may be incompatible with the principles of the
> WTO rules-based multilateral trading system**, where countries have
> undertaken market access and other obligations under the condition of
> non discrimination and in respect of market principles.

([OECD Source](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/docserver/5k4869ckqk7l-en.pdf?expires=1704234006&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=EC169590098525F71C277EA1E36E5B5F))

Which country has the highest number of state-owned enterprises after China?

I am assuming China has the most, although I could be wrong, so I was wondering what was the country with the most state-owned enterprises after China, because after reading this report, it seems that state owned enterprises confer a lot of unfair advantages that the WTO wasn't able to fully address and thus it makes sense for countries to have them.

> Analysts say the initiative is unlikely to significantly improve
> efficiency among the China’s 130,000 state-owned companies

https://www.scmp.com/economy/china-economy/article/3092339/china-approves-plan-boost-prominence-state-firms-despite

Comment: I think the "number" may be meaningless, as lot of small enterprises might be not as important as a big one. Maybe a % of GDP would be a more reliable indicator.

Comment: You should also note that I) not all state owned enterprises benefit from those advantages and ii) in some fields or locations private companies may receive those benefits. For example, subsidies are fairly common in farming and public transportation in the West.

Comment: Agree with SJuan76, the number tells you very little. For example, imagine a country where each city has an SOE that runs all the pet shops in that city. Now imagine they restructure and every individual pet shop is a separate SOE. Now they restructure again into a single SOE responsible for all the pet shops in the entire country. You get 3 radically different numbers in those 3 scenarios, with basically the same amount of economic activity run by SOEs. The number doesn't depend on anything meaningful about "how much SOE" the country uses, just on the fairly arbitrary organisational structure

Comment: Given that China is the 2nd biggest economy - after the US - by a large margin, you will be unlikely to find anyone else with "more SOEs".  As a percentage of GDP would make a better question.  But in which case you can probably bring in old stalwarts that are more centrally planned:  I bet North Korea has more SOE / GDP, for example.

Comment: What is state owned? Only central government owned firms? Only majority government owned firms? Or any firm with significant government ownership?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is lots of data but there are few definitive answers due to definitional issues and the need to figure out how you should choose to rank countries. The ranking method proposed in the question doesn't make a lot of sense and is vague about what counts at a state owned enterprise.

For example, in the U.S., the United States Postal Service is a single state owned enterprise. But, if individual post offices were owned by local governments, then each of the 33,641 post offices in the U.S. might count as a separate state owned enterprise.

A small country could have 100% state owned enterprises yet still not rank very high by number of state owned enterprises because it has only one of each kind of firm.

Within Europe, the range is illustrated in the following chart (from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264999321000730)) measured by % of assets owned by state owned and partially state owned enterprises:

[image]

Another example is [here](https://www.elibrary.imf.org/view/journals/001/2017/221/article-A001-en.xml), which also illustrates the point that state owned enterprises can be very different in importance in an economy, as measured by output v. employment:

[image]

By percentage of GDP that comes from state owned enterprises, oil rich countries with a state owned oil company rank high, but may not have a very large share of employment, and this may not impact the overall character of the economy much.

Determining the number of state owned enterprises is tricky and varies wildly depending upon how you define it.

A [2023 World Bank study](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/server/api/core/bitstreams/dd966c87-fc56-4871-9438-01dd94a2059f/content) distinguishes between businesses of the state (BOS), that are at least 10% government owned by some government, and state owned enterprises (SOE), which are majority owned or more, and controlled, by a central government. It's top line result is shown in the following chart, which looks at how many economic sectors have some BOS and SOE involvement, not the percentage of the economy devote to them (which is about 17% of global GDP):

[image]

This shows immense disparities in the number of state owned enterprises in individual countries based upon the definitions used.

Russia has high levels of SOEs by many measures and would be a contender for a runner up to China by almost any measure.

Comment: Why is China missing from Figure O.1?

Comment: @user103496 The study didn't consider it, probably because SOEs are so pervasive in China and also possibly because it was hard to get good data.

Answer (score 3):

Some googling has yielded this [research with a chart](https://cepr.org/voxeu/columns/state-owned-enterprises-global-economy-reason-concern) this chart:

[image: State ownership share per country]

So it is UAE followed by Russia, which is a weird phenomenon. Is Emirates Airline a SOE? That one would be quite efficient.

Please note that it is a slightly different answer. It measures state involvement in top ten enterprises instead of counting them arithmetically. The latest would be meaningless because long tail of small enterprises will drown the numbers in noize.

It is also a decade old now.

Comment: What exactly do the numbers on that graph represent?

Comment: @JoeW It is the percentage of the top firms in the country that are state owned.

Comment: @ohwilleke that should really be in the answer though not sure how that answers the question on how many as we don't know how many a percentage translates into.

Comment: @JoeW: "an equally weighted average of SOE shares of sales, assets and market
values among country‘s top ten companies"

Comment: @user103496 what exactly is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @JoeW: I'm not completely sure either. Skimming through the paper, it doesn't seem very well done (and the English is not very good--not a good sign given that in economics, English is the universal language of communication).